# code for cycle detection is not finding returning the right number of cycles in directed graph in Java?

Tags: java, graph, depth-first-search, directed-graph, cyclic-graph

I have code written for calculating the no of cycles in a directed graph using `DFS`. The method to check if a cycle exists or not works fine. I now iterate through all the vertices (which I have in a HashMap) and check if a vertex is unvisited, then check if a cycle exists, if so increment the counter by 1. Now the code breaks, it does not give the right number of cycles eg: for the graph with following edges:

```
(A B),(B C),(C E),(E A),(B E)
```

Here is my code;

```
public int getTotalCyclesinDir(){
    clearAll();
    int count=0;
    for (Vertex v : vertexMap.values()) {
        if (!v.isVisited && isCyclicDirected(v))
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}

public boolean isCyclicDirected(Vertex v){
    if (!v.isVisited){
        v.setVisited(true);
        Iterator<Edge> e = v.adj.iterator();
        while (e.hasNext()){
            Vertex t = e.next().target;
            if (!t.isVisited) {
                if (isCyclicDirected(t))
                    return true;
            }
            else return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    else return true;
}
```

Comment: Which number do you expect and what does the algorithm return?

Comment: I expect 2 because there are two cycles, but it returns only one

Comment: Also, I see there are too many return statements in my `isCyclicDirected` method. is there a way to simplify it?

Comment: if you need other part of code, I can add them

Comment: In if / else, I'd put the short case first, in particular if this can avoid a not. Also, if you return conditionally, you don't really need an explicit else after that.

Comment: what you mean by return conditionally? or which line of code you mean?

Comment: First lines of isCycleDirected could be `if (v.visited) { return true }`. After that, no else or indent. Weed out the simple cases quickly while you progress through the method -- at the end it's harder to remember or look up what a lonely else actually belongs to...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42071/discussion-between-user1988876-and-stefan-haustein)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two problems with your algorithm:

- `isCyclicDirected` just detects whether there is any cycle in the graph. You can't use it directly to count cycles. For instance, your algorithm will count two cycles in (A B) (B A) (C A) because (C A) connects to a visited node.
- If you want to detect two cycles in your example, your detection needs to be edge based instead of vertex based. (B E) forms a cycle but both B and E are marked visited from previous runs.

Comment: I see your point. 1) what you mean by edge based, can you elaborate a little 2) in  `isCyclicDirected` method, I have too many returns, is that all necessary or any room for simplification..Thanks

Comment: Assume there is a river and you want to count bridges. You start on one side of the bridge and mark the shore as visited. Then you cross the bridge and mark the other side as visited. Then you conclude that there is only one bridge because you have visited both sides.

Comment: I made changes to code and implemented differently to keep track of edges. Still I have some issues, which I posted here..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20253255/couting-back-edges-to-get-the-number-of-cylces-in-a-directed-graph